# Update _id of a document elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to update the _id of the document that is already indexed in elasticsearch?

Java code is the following:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
params.put("newid", "newid");
UpdateRequest ur = new UpdateRequest("test", "test", "id")
          .script(new Script("updateId", ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE, "groovy", params));
```

groovy script:

```
ctx._id=newid
```

**EDIT:**

Now the id is a field and the _id is autogenerated by elastic. Whenever there is an update, I search for the id and give it to the UpdateRequest.

Comment: You cannot change the `_id` of an existing document. However, you can definitely create a new document with the new `_id` and delete the document with the old one.

Comment: Which means I have to extract the _source from the old one, then create the new one and delete the old. 3 operations.

Comment: Which ES version are you using? Why do you want to change the id? Is this a one time operation or are you going to do this regularly?

Comment: 2.3.1 I wonder what is the cost of putting the _id in the _source (for delete and query)

Comment: It may happen often. It's on rename of a document.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself why you need to change the ID (which is supposed to be eternal)

Comment: Because documents change and the id for my docs is derived from somewhere else (where I need them to point to after an update). Id is not the best way to do it, that's why there is a backup plan of putting this information into a _source field. Yet, then I will have to delete by query and update by query to identify the right docs to operate on. Thanks for your reply, though.

Comment: There will be some trial and error until I get to the point of "all set" :D

Comment: Ok, don't hesitate if you have other questions.

Comment: thanks, much appreciated